# How to display custome post in single page or index page my wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I used the plugin in my WordPress CPT UI and I create a custome post product 3-4 custom post which I want to display in a single page or index page both of one then how to display where I should coding I don't understand please anybody who knows about the answer and plz explain me step by step with it I'm confused.

I used the theme which had  many pages and index.php Archiv.php, single.php, page.php, and  function.php I confused about which page I would like to code

This is my custome post type and this code my function.php now i trying to performed my template-product.php to display all code . how can i do this  anybody know plz send me code .

function cptui_register_my_cpts() {

```
/**
 * Post Type: products.
 */

$labels = array(
    "name" => __( "products", "twentyseventeen" ),
    "singular_name" => __( "product", "twentyseventeen" ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( "products", "twentyseventeen" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "delete_with_user" => false,
    "show_in_rest" => true,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
    "has_archive" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "product", "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "menu_position" => 10,
    "menu_icon" => "dashicons-cart",
    "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "excerpt", "custom-fields", "revisions", "author" ),
);

register_post_type( "product", $args );
```

}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts' );

function cptui_register_my_cpts_product() {

```
/**
 * Post Type: products.
 */

$labels = array(
    "name" => __( "products", "twentyseventeen" ),
    "singular_name" => __( "product", "twentyseventeen" ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( "products", "twentyseventeen" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "delete_with_user" => false,
    "show_in_rest" => true,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
    "archive" => true,

    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "product", "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "menu_position" => 10,
    "menu_icon" => "dashicons-cart",
    "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "excerpt", "custom-fields", "revisions", "author" ),
);

register_post_type( "product", $args );
```

}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_product' );

Answer (score 0):

Check this, here is the full description about WordPress file structure and file name.

```
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/post-template-files/
```

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is about custom post type single & archive/index pages display in general**

For every custom post type following pages should be created in theme directory

**Single Page:**

```
Single page will be single-{custom post type name}.php
```

*Example*:

```
For custom post type name "courses" single page will be "single-courses.php"
```

**Archive/Index Page:**

```
Archive/Index page will be archive-{custom post type name}.php
```

*Example*:

```
For custom post type name "courses" archive page will be "archive-courses.php"
```

**For further study please visit: [Post Template Files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/post-template-files/)**